# Failed to set a Path parameter

Tags: powershell, parameters, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

Im writing a PowerShell Skript that takes relevant Data from a CSV File and creates a new CSV file. 
Everything works as expected, but im having trouble in setting up a Path variable.
Everytime i launch the Skript im asked for a path, even tho ive specified the path in the Param block.

```
Param (
        # Param1 Pfadparameter
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
                   Position=0,
                   ValueFromPipeline=$true,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
                   ValueFromRemainingArguments=$false, 
                   ParameterSetName='Parameter Set 1')]
                   $Path = '.C:\Users\wkivan3\Desktop\Sheduling\Aufgabe\kurz.csv'
    )
```

here is the line that uses the $Path parameter:

```
$Accountdaten = Get-Content -Path $Path | convertfrom-csv -Delimiter ';'
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Instead of `Get-Content -Path $Path | convertfrom-csv -Delimiter ';'` you could just use `Import-Csv -Path $Path -Delimiter ';'`

Comment: Look at that, works perfectly! Thanks a ton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `Mandatory = $true` in the parameter section, it means, you **must** provide that when running the script. Make that `$false` so that its optional. If you dont provide the value, it will use the one you defined as the default value but if you do provide value to `-Path` variable when calling your script, it will override the default path.

Also, remove the `.` before `C:\Users` in the `$Path`.

```
Param (
        # Param1 Pfadparameter
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, # Change this to $false.
                   Position=0,
                   ValueFromPipeline=$true,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
                   ValueFromRemainingArguments=$false, 
                   ParameterSetName='Parameter Set 1')]
                   $Path = 'C:\Users\xyz\Desktop\Sheduling\temp\kurz.csv'
    )

powershell script.ps1 -Path "C:\NewPath.csv" # will use C:\NewPath.csv as the $path
powershell script.ps1                        # uses the C:\users\xyz\desktop\sheduling\temp\kurz.csv path.
```